# JS Smooth Scroll Vertical & Horizontal Function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a multisite in a one-page, where everytime a link is clicked, it automatically scrolls to that element in the page (all div elements).
The function works but it still jumps to the given element.

Here's the code I've got so far and the elements I use to call the function:

```
<li class="topli">
    <a id="toplink" onclick="Scroll('#home')" href="javascript:void(0);">HOME</a>
</li>

<script>
    function Scroll(element) {
        var ID = element.split('#').join('');
        var target = document.getElementById(ID);
        var offset = target.getBoundingClientRect();

        console.log("X:",offset.x,"Y:",offset.y);

        if (window.scrollY != offset.y) {
            window.scroll(window.scrollY, offset.y);
        }

        if (window.scrollX != offset.x) {
            window.scroll(window.scrollX, offset.x);
        }
    }
</script>
```

If needed I'll add a more detailed code to a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Tektiv That is done in the function itself, if you look at the first line inside the function you'll see I used the `.split` and `.join` functions to substract the `#` from `#home` and then just add nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Create jQuery helper for this

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.goTo = function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 'fast');

        return this; 
}
})(jQuery);
```

And use like

```
$('#el').goTo();
```

Comment: Initially I wanted to make this without jQuery, since I'm not very familiar with it yet, but considering you said 'helper', is there a way to include JQuery without having to include all the directories? Also what does `.fn.` refer to?

Comment: .fn - it's jQuery contract to create widgets. So yes - you can call this function with your element context. And you need to include only jquery reference.

Comment: Alright, well I'm still trying to do this with plain JS but I'll keep this in mind if it doesn't work out. Also is there a plain JS equivalent for `.animate`? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I tried doing it with CSS3, but can't get that to work either.. Thanks for the help anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try this for scrolling vertically (where `100` is the rate of scroll):

```
const goTo = (targetEl) => {
  const elm = document.querySelector(targetEl);
  const offset = elm.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  if (offset > window.innerHeight) {
    window.scroll(0, window.scrollY + 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
      goTo(targetEl);
    }, 16.666);
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

Call it like so:

```
goTo('#scroll-target');
```

or on click:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.long-div').addEventListener('click', () => {
    goTo('#scroll-target');
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how this one is different from mine? I see the same but with different codes.. Also what is `const` and what does `() => {..}` do in the `setTimeout`? I'm kind of slow in understanding what JS does and why it does it, so if you could explain to me what the differences are then I'd be really grateful!

Comment: It's has similar functionality but is now "recursive". Basically it's saying only scroll the screen 100px at a time, if the target div and the page aren't aligned call the function again and do it max 60 times per second(1000/60). This give us a smooth animation. You could also look into `window.requestAnimationFrame` for re-invoking the function.. As for `const` and the arrow function have a look into ES6 syntax.

Comment: Doesn't work, man, I'm getting expression statement errors in the `window.addEventlistener` and in the `setTimeout` of the `const` `goTo()`..

Answer (score 0):

Vertical smooth scroll, easy and native way:

```
let element = document.querySelector('#element');

// Vertical Scroll
this.element.scrollTo({
    left: element.offsetLeft,
    behavior: 'smooth'
})

// Horizontal Scroll
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
```

docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo